# Extract content between tag

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace all tags in a XML formatted string with a white space. For example, after replacement, `<student x = 100>Nick Miles</student>` would become  `Nick Miles`  with two whitespace around `Nick Miles`.

I have tried `str.replaceAll("<ref.*?>", " ")` and `str.replaceAll(</ref>, " ")`.

It works for most cases. However, if there is no `>` following `ref`, the content in the text would be eliminated. I know is about greedy qualifier, but I just fail to fix it. Could some please propose a possible solution?

Comment: Use a lazy modifier, so `.*?`, not a possessive one.

Answer (score 1):

Why use the greedy quantifier at all? You want exactly the opposite: for the regex to stop matching `.*` once the first `>` is encountered. That's what a **lazy** quantifier is for. Just replace `+` with `?` and you're done.